# Need a Java Hibernate Spring Rules Solution for multiple clients?

Tags: spring, hibernate, rule-engine

Suppose I have a system which sells tires, and this system will be used by 20 different Tire selling companies. Each company has their own set of rules on how they sell tires and the system needs to handle those rules.

**For instance:** Company A uses the system and they are allowed to sell 4 different brand tires to any client. Company B may only sell 4 of the same brand tires to a client.

So the rules engine must be applied based on which company is currently using the system.

I know I can build 20 if's in every java object to check which company is busy using the system, but is there some sort of implementation for Spring/Hibernate which I can use where I can put all the rules per company in a central place and then act on them accordingly? Thus leaving the core of the system as is and only adding more rules to the "rules repo" as we get more and more clients with different rules?

And now I am really pushing my luck here, but some sort of implementation example or docs will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hey why not trying some design pattern for that.
May be you can try Factory pattern.

It will provide you the required object of class based on you requirements.
Later you can add more classes and it will work.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at it and how I can use it for my problem.